# How to properly call a function from a functional component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Might be a newb question but I am a beginner in React Native and am having a hard time understanding how to call functions in my return method from a functional component. If I return anything in my searchUser function, it does not output on my screen. Can you please help me understand how to properly call this function and return the components in it? I obviously have a larger function I am trying to complete by having the user search using this function, but I at least want to understand how to properly call a function first and output the component in it onto my screen.

```
  const Map = ({navigation}) => {

    //used to search 
    const searchUser = async () => {
        return <Text> hello </Text>
    }

  return (
      <Container>
        <ScrollView>
            <Text style = {styles.titleStyle}> Map </Text>
            <List>
               {searchUser()}
            </List>
        </ScrollView>
      </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will **render nothing because it returns a Promise** and not a Component.

You need to use hook such as [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to implement your searchUser.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
 
  //used to search 
    const searchUser = async () => {
        return  {} // fetch data
    }
 
 const Map = ({navigation}) => {

function MyComponent({data}) {

  return(
    <Text>{data}</Texte>
  )
}

  const [result, setResult] = useState({})
  
  useEffect( async () => { // async declaration because we use await
  
  // call all your fetch
  const data = await searchUser()
  
  setResult(data);
  
  });
   

  return (
      <Container>
        <ScrollView>
            <Text style = {styles.titleStyle}> Map </Text>
            <MyComponent data={result} /> // call your component to show
        </ScrollView>
      </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: I got the error Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component? Is this because I'm returning an array in my searchUser function?

Comment: This error mean that in your code some String are outside the <Text></Text> balise.

Comment: I figured out how to make it a List component instead!  I also had to change the useEffect to have an empty array at the end and put the async function inside it and call my functions there instead of as a parameter (my code didn't like it your way). Thanks so much for your help though, I finally understand how functional components work with functional calls and returning components. This really helped me.